# Small white space between grid and elements inside

Tags: html, css

so if you run the code below you will see some white space in the bottom (if you go fullscreen it should appear on the side) between the grid border and the squares border, i can't figure out what's causing it or whether i'm doing something wrong.

```css
.board {
  display: grid;
border: 1px solid black;
flex: 1;
grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
height: 500px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
}

.boards-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 16px;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boards-container">
  <div class="board p-board"> 
        <div id="0-0" class="square"></div>
        <div id="0-1" class="square"></div>
        <div id="1-0" class="square"></div>
        <div id="1-1" class="square"></div>
            
   </div>
        
 <div class="board c-board">
        <div id="0-0" class="square"></div>
        <div id="0-1" class="square"></div>
        <div id="1-0" class="square"></div>
        <div id="1-1" class="square"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: what white space are you refering to? I see a lot of white background and unused white space (which is to be expected with a white background).

Comment: inside the grid between the outer border (the grid border) and the squares border

Comment: there's no white space between the grid border and squares border, set outer border color to red to see that

Comment: Are you talking about the space between the boards. If not, running the example with Firefox I don't see any trouble.

Comment: @GrafiCode i added a picture if you could see it it shows what i get on my screen

Comment: Yes, this is a well known phenomenon. For the people who can't see it, try different zoom levels. What happens is that the system is trying to map part CSS pixels to the several screen pixels that make up one CSS pixel on modern screens. Screen pixels can get 'left behind'. As I zoomed I saw off and on the two central-most vertical lines merging sometimes and sometimes with a small white space between them.

Comment: @AHaworth is there a fix for it or something to hide it?

Comment: Remove the outer border.

Comment: It depends on what your real use case is. If you don't need a separate border on the outer element then just remove it as @zer00ne suggests. Will this solve it for you?

Comment: @AHaworth yeah it did i should have thought of that quite earlier but got caught trying to fix it anyways thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

just add body,html{margin:0;padding:0;} to your css

```css
.board {
  display: grid;
border: 1px solid black;
flex: 1;
grid-template-columns:repeat(2,1fr);
height: 500px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
}

.boards-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 16px;
    padding: 16px;
}

div{
background:lightblue;}

body, html{
margin:0;padding:0;}
```

```html
<div class="boards-container"><div class="board p-board"> 
        <div id="0-0" class="square"></div>
        <div id="0-1" class="square"></div>
        <div id="1-0" class="square"></div>
        <div id="1-1" class="square"></div>
            
   </div>
        
 <div class="board c-board">
        <div id="0-0" class="square"></div>
        <div id="0-1" class="square"></div>
        <div id="1-0" class="square"></div>
        <div id="1-1" class="square"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the problem presented. In fact, on my Edge Windows10 laptop right now I see two vertial lines rather than one merged one when running your snippet - they happen to be on the rightmost part of the leftmost two rectangles, but different zoom levels give different results.

Comment: I have no idea of what you are talking about.  There is some margin or padding on body or html THAT is causing the problem described.  Unable to produce your stated results. suggest you invest in a new machine ad use chrome

Comment: Hi, I have a hi spec laptop and am on Edge/Chrome. The problem is seen on the middle vertical lines in my case, two lines very close together although the logic says there should be one. It's a bit like a rounding error.

Comment: ahh, I now see the issue at zoom levels of 150, 175 and 250.  Interesting

Comment: Can happen quite a bit I find, particularly come across it when trying to fill an element with a pseudo element, there's sometimes a tiny gap between the border of the element and the edge of the pseudo element background. (in that case I hack round it by making the pseudo element just a bit bigger and displacing it slightly).

Answer (score 0):

We can be seen when zooming in the page, this could be a half pixel, which is being behaved differently with each browser, sometimes it doesn't.

if we see in normally without zoom, there is nothing. You can quick fix by adding box-shadow or outline css to overlook the zoom.